# Setting up Eclipse for C development using CDT plugin

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.5.2. I want to install the CDT plugin so that I can compile C/C++ programs.

I attempted to install the CDT plugin and it failed, given the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support 1.1.0.201206111645 (org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group 1.1.0.201206111645)
  Missing requirement: C/C++ Managed Builder UI 8.1.0.201206111645 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui 8.1.0.201206111645) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui.console [3.5.100,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CDT GCC Cross Compiler Support 1.1.0.201206111645 (org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc 1.1.0.201206111645)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui 8.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support 1.1.0.201206111645 (org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group 1.1.0.201206111645)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc [1.1.0.201206111645]
```

Has anyone managed to install/use the CDT plugin with Eclipse v 3.5.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have GCC installed? If I remember correctly CDT does not include the compiler. You need to find a C compiler and install it before installing CDT.

Comment: Yes, I have gcc devtools installed. Most of my programming is C/C++.